# Have unchecked checkbox yield a value in Django

Tags: html, django, webforms, checkbox

I'm asking users of my Django app a lot of yes/no questions, and I'd like to do so using checkboxes rather than radio buttons. The problem is that I want a `value` for each checkbox, instead of each one that is checked.

I found this trick using additional [`hidden` checkboxes](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/unchecked-checkbox-values/), which looks like a nice hack, but [one of the comments](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/unchecked-checkbox-values/#comment-6593) raised some doubts in my mind:

> This is not correct. Both values will get submitted, HTML allows [multiple] values with the same name.

Is that true? If so, how will the Django `HttpRequest.POST` handle multiple values for the same name/key?

Comment: It's your app, but you're intentionally subverting the way HTML forms work. That's the sort of thing that bites me when I come back to it months later (or come onboard a new project).

Comment: @Hank Gay: are you suggesting I use radio buttons instead?

Comment: Yes. Yes/No radio buttons are the standard way of achieving the functionality you want. You are, of course, free to do it differently if you want, as long as you're aware that you're violating the norm. I realize this isn't actually an answer to the question you asked, hence I left it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTML allows users to submit multiple values for a single key, Django has to use a specialized data structure to accommodate that possibility.  The result is the MultiValueDict, which is what `request.GET` and `request.POST` are instances of under the hood.  You can browse the code for that structure here: http://djangoapi.quamquam.org/trunk/django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDict-class.html

The short story though is that you can access the first value with a simple dict lookup like `request.POST['mykey']` and the list of all values like `request.POST.getlist('mykey')`.

That said, as some other commenters have noted, there is probably a better way to handle the use case you describe.  Radio buttons with a yes/no option are one solution, though perhaps less usable from the user's perspective.  I'd think the best way to handle it is to rethink how you're processing the form, and using the Django Forms library where possible instead of doing low-level processing of the raw POST data.

Comment: I'll stick to the `getlist` method for the demo that's due the day after tomorrow, but I'll rethink the solution for the final version. Thanks for pointing out the Forms library.

Comment: Sounds good.  Anyone who's done real programming work can understand the need for a quick, if suboptimal, solution :)  I think you'll find using forms will save you a lot of pain in the long run.